# NSCache-not always cleaned?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSCache` in which i am loading from and to- images to be displayed in collection view .
When i have to reload data to the collection view, i must clean the cache, because otherwise the collection view will find old data in there and reload it instead of the new data.

So before i reload the collection i clean my cache :

```
[self.myCache removeAllObjects];
```

Which sometimes, is not working, and i still see the old images in the collection view .
Is there another way to go all over its values and clean them ? Why is it not being cleared ?

Here is how i load and get images from and to :

```
-(UIImage*) imageForIndexPathRow:(NSNumber *) number
{
    return [self.myCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cache:%d",[number intValue]] ];
}

-(void) setImage:(UIImage*) image forIndexPathRow:(NSNumber *) number
{
    if(image)
        [self.myCache setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cache:%d",[number intValue]]  ];
}
```

EDIT:
This is how i check the cache before load image to cell(in another thread) :

```
UIImage *imageToSet=nil;
                        UIImage *cacheImg=[self imageForIndexPathRow:[NSNumber numberWithLong:cell.tag]];
                        if(cacheImg==nil)
                        {
                            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:1];
                            imageToSet=image;
                            //save to cache
                            [self setImage:image forIndexPathRow:[NSNumber numberWithLong:cell.tag]];

                        }
                        else
                         imageToSet=cacheImg;
```

Comment: are you sure it's not a problem with cell reuse? I see an indexpath based method there, so I suspect you are using a tableview

Comment: I use collection view, as i wrote in the question, but i dont think it is,because when a new cell is being created i load a new image to its image view and clear the old. is there something you think i might do/check to know for sure ?

Comment: Where are the images coming from? The web? URL loading system caching?

Comment: the images are coming from the web, every time a new cell is being created, his imageView.image= nil , and than i load a new image in a background thread, and when its done i set that image to the imageView of that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from CollectionView cell reusing

you need to implement the `else` case, like this

```
- (UIImage *)imageForIndexPathRow:(NSNumber *) number
{
    UIImage *cachedImage = [self.myCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cache:%d", [number intValue]]];
    if (cachedImage) {
        return cachedImage;
    }
    // Otherwise load it from web
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...yourImageURL"]];
    UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    // Cache it back
    [self.myCache setObject:loadedImage forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cache:%d", [number intValue]]];
    return loadedImage;
}
```

and the `cellForRow` should look like this (my example is on UITableView, but you can port it to CollectionView)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellId"];
    cell.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [self imageForIndexPathRow:@(indexPath.row)];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           cell.image = image;
       });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but this is what i do, check my edit .

Comment: hmm.. set a breakpoint on if(cacheImg==nil), and see what happens after [self.myCache removeAllObjects];, does it gets into else block?

Comment: ok i think i got it maybe you can help. When it happens is when i reload the collection, but 1 moment before it, i am scrolling to the start of the collection -WITH animation set to YES (scrollToVisibile) . what happens is that sometimes, when he finish the  auto scrolling, he starts to load in background ,the old images,and than the new ones. I think i have to set a bolean to exit the cellForItemAtIndexPath: method when auto scrolling ?

Comment: i think thats the case, he loads twice some indexes , he first load index 0,1,2 from the auto scrolling, than somehow i see again the same indexes when he finish the auto scrolling .

Comment: Try to call delayed reload, after autoscrolling, maybe this will resolve the issue.

Comment: ok you where right. i did things wrong. i take your answer. thanks.

Comment: well , i use your code, its better, but the problem still occurs when i scroll with animation to the start, after reloading data. if i reload without animation, its not happening.

Comment: try this code after scrolling, dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    });

Comment: I think the problem is that, collectionView calls celLForIndexPath, when scrolling to top

Comment: yes it do calls the cellforindexpath , but this should not cause any problem because it has to call the right index for the right cell . i guess it calls it for the cells all over the way up, than when some of them finish loading the image, its being loaded to the first cells, although its belongs to lower cells..

Comment: i guess i can solve it by setting a boolean when auto scroll, and in the method cellforindexatpath check that boolean, and load cells only for indexes 0,1,2...but i doubt if it works..